# Android openGL ES normals

Tags: android, opengl-es, normals

So yesterday I wrote WaveFront .obj 3D model loader which now works fine(doesn't support everything tho) so I wrote simple test to draw any 3D model on the screen which all worked fine until I was adding lighting to the scene. The light appeared but it seems like the normals are still in their default state. I am very unsure what should i use as target when generating buffers(as theres GL_NORMAL_ARRAY, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER etc.) for normals as I couldn't find any tutorial about it using buffer objects for those:

```
package com.Ruuhkis.opengl;

import static javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.Ruuhkis.opengl.model.Indices;
import com.Ruuhkis.opengl.model.Loader;
import com.Ruuhkis.opengl.model.Model;
import com.Ruuhkis.opengl.model.Polygon;
import com.Ruuhkis.opengl.model.Vertex;

public class TextureRenderer implements Renderer {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, normalBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    private int attribVBO, attribIBO, attribNBO;
    private Context context;
    private float rotation = 0;
    private float[] vertices = 
        {-0.8f, -0.8f, 0f,
        0.8f, -0.8f, 0f,
        0.8f, 0.8f, 0f,
        -0.8f, 0.8f, 0f};

    private float[] normals = 
        {0f};

    private short[] indices =
        {0, 3, 2,
        0, 2, 1};

    public TextureRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        Model model = Loader.loadModel(context.getAssets(), "test.txt");

        vertices = new float[model.getVerticeList().size() * 3];

        int i = 0;

        for(Vertex v: model.getVerticeList()) {
            vertices[i++] = v.getX();
            vertices[i++] = v.getY();
            vertices[i++] = v.getZ();
            //Log.v("vertice", v.toString() + " sa");
        }

        i = 0;

        indices = new short[model.getPolygonList().size() * 3];
        normals = new float[model.getPolygonList().size() * 3];

        for(Polygon p: model.getPolygonList()) {
            for(Indices in: p.getIndiceList()) {
                normals[i] = vertices[in.getNormalIndex()];
                indices[i++] = (short) in.getVertexIndex();         
            }
        }

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.flip();

        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(normals.length * 4);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        normalBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
        normalBuffer.put(normals);
        normalBuffer.flip();

        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indices);
        indexBuffer.flip();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glColor4f(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, -10f);
        rotation += 1f;
        gl.glRotatef(rotation, 1f, 1f, 0f);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;

        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attribVBO);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, attribIBO);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY, attribNBO);
        gl11.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        gl11.glNormalPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0);
        gl11.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
        gl.glFlush();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45f, (float)width / (float)height, 1f, 100f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT1);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{0f, 0f, 0f, 1f}));
        gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 1f}));
        gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 1f}));

        gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_SPECULAR, FloatBuffer.wrap(new float[]{1f, 1f, 1f, 1f}));
        gl.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS,128f);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1f);
        GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;
        int[] buffer = new int[1];
        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        attribVBO = buffer[0];
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, attribVBO);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.length * 4, vertexBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, -1);

        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        attribIBO = buffer[0];
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, attribIBO);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.length * 2, indexBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, -1);

        gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
        attribNBO = buffer[0];
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY, attribNBO);
        gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY, normals.length * 4, normalBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY, -1);
    }
}
```

[image]

so, the default normals are 0, 0, -1 or 0, 0, 1 and the default camera is looking at -5, and as the model rotates the light just goes away just like it is when theres no normals, I've got something similar to this work with computer but i didn't use VBOs etc. so I can't compare the code, I am pretty sure theres something wrong with uploading the normal buffer or binding it! :( help me! :(

Comment: Just a quick guess : are the exported normals normalized? If not, do you normalize them at some point (because I couldnt find evidence of that in your code after a quick glance)?

Comment: Yeah, the normals are exported and loaded from .obj file, I also myself checked if the normals were loading, and they were.

Comment: that is not my question; I'm sure you load the objects normals. What I am asking is : are they normalized? In other words: is their length 1? If that is not the case, you cannot do correct lighting.

Comment: Oh sorry.. English sure isn't my mothertongue. Anyway, yeah, their length is 1, I just tested it out and their values is between -1 to 1.2~

Answer (score 1):

To explain my comment on your question a little further :

ou need to make sure your normals are "normalized"; that means their magnitude (length) must be 1. Some .obj exporters do this for you; but it's a good thing to do this yourself.

Quoted from: http://www.fundza.com/vectors/normalize/index.html

Given a vector "a" (or normal "a") : a[3 1 2]  (So : ax = 3, ay = 1, az = 2)

The magnitude (length) of the vector is : |a| = sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay) + (az * az))

```
length = sqrt((ax * ax) + (ay * ay) + (az * az)) 
length = sqrt(9 + 1 + 4) = 3.742
```

To normalize vector "a" we divide by the length:

```
x = ax/|a|;
y = ay/|a|;
z = az/|a|;

x = 3.0 / 3.742 = 0.802
y = 1.0 / 3.742 = 0.267
z = 2.0 / 3.742 = 0.534
```

You need to apply this to your normals *before* you create your buffer in order to get correct lighting.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that and for try but it seems like that's not the problem. I am using blender which normalizes them automatically. And as I stated on my comment on your post before, their values are from -1 to ~1.2, just to make sure they're normalized. :P

Comment: That cannot be right; length must be *exactly* 1 (not -1; not 1.2). Or.. if you mean by "values" the xyz components then that is wrong as well. The xyz components can be negative or positive, but always between -1 and 1.

Comment: Anyway, if you are convinced that your normals are correct, you should post an image and explain what is wrong with the lighting. I'm trying to help you but you're not making it easy for me.

Comment: the length is 1 but the values are between -1 and 1.2, I'll post images, hold on! :)